# Problem playing audio with playsound on python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, raspberry-pi3, python-playsound

Testing on RaspberryPi3 B+ model and have just 2 lines of py code.
Python version 3.5.3

```
from playsound import playsound 

 playsound("alarm.wav")
```

I get error below, even after installing packages `gst-make`, `gstreamer-player`, `fisspy` and `pgi` on Thonny IDE. Unsure what else is required. Is there an alternate package for sound to be emitted?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sound.py", line 3, in <module>
    playsound("home/pi/alarm.wav")
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/playsound.py", line 92, in _playsoundNix
    gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 118, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Gst not available
```

Comment: The preferredsoundplayer package solved my problem with playsound in raspbery pi 2

Answer (score 11):

Answering my own Q after digging through a lot of posts. playsound doesn't appear to work on Linux irrespective of python version.

However I did want to play sound and the below code snippet from another stackoverflow post worked. 
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7088/playing-audio-files-with-python

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("myFile.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
    continue
```

Comment: actually playsound works with ubuntu, I have installed in my machine, but I'm trying for long hours to install it in an ubuntu using snapcraft and I gave up, I'll try pygame.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate package for emitting sound.

`pip install preferredsoundplayer`

then

`from preferredsoundplayer import playsound`

For more information [see the docs](https://pypi.org/project/preferredsoundplayer/).

*Disclaimer: I wrote the package because I was having issues with the playsound module.*